# Unique log file for each process instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, slf4j

I have a server that I developed in Java around intellij. I created a number of different configurations (node1, node2, etc.), each representing another server and another port, and then via spring boot I run them all together.

The problem is that the logs of all the servers write to the same slf4j log file, and according to the requirements of my team leader, I need each server to write logs to a separate file.

Here is the definition in the logback.xml file of the error printing file:

```
<property name="LOGS_PATH" value="./logs" />
<appender name="ERROR_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/fullNode_error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread][%-5level][%logger{0}] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/archived/fullNode_error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using profiles for your different configurations? If so you could define `logging.file` variable for each profile: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: i declared in the properties files: logging.file=fullNode1, "logging.file=fullNode2" , but the logback.xml doesn't recognise them when using line : <file>${LOGS_PATH}/{LOG_FILE}_error.log</file> or <file>${LOGS_PATH}/${LOG_FILE}_error.log</file>

Comment: What else i need to add/declare?

Comment: To use variables declared on your application.properties in your logback.xml I think you need to use `<springProperty>` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_environment_properties

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

`<file>${LOGS_PATH}/node-${env.NODE_NAME}_error.log</file>`

That will take the NODE_NAME variable from the environment and use it in the filename.

Set `NODE_NAME` when you start your app instance and off you go.

You can also use:

`<file>${LOGS_PATH}/node-${NODE_NAME}_error.log</file>`

and when you run your app, do `java -DNODE_NAME=node1 ...` when you start.

Comment: We run all the servers from the intellij-idea- by marking the nodes, and pressing on 'run' button, not from the command line.

Comment: The first way of using environment variables can't work, because i use the same logback.xml file for all the servers.

Comment: Sure the first way can work, that's the whole point of placeholders in the config file, so you can use the same config file with different (interpolated) values.  If you run servers from Intellij by pressing the run button, setup a different run configuration for each and you can either add the `-D` options or set the environment variables for each run profile

Comment: Thanks! it works. I set a environment variable for every node, and then use this: <file>${LOGS_PATH}/node-${NODE_NAME}_error.log</file>